# Can't run Meteor app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, github

I'm trying to run the [react-sticky-scroll](https://github.com/themeteorchef/react-sticky-scroll) project from GitHub.

- I extracted it from GitHub.
- I navigated to the root directory using the command line.
- I then used, `npm start`.

When I go to `localhost:3000` I get a page with title Express and "welcome to express" at the top. Nothing else.

**Question**

How can I run this app?

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It seems that `npm start` does work, but the content isn't running on localhost:3000. Is there perhaps something else that I need to navigate to?

Answer (score 2):

#### Edited: the project you are cloning is not react project. It's a boilerplate project on Meteor. You need to run `meteor npm install` for more details you can follow its documentation on following link.

https://themeteorchef.com/base/getting-started

When you clone any starter/base project you need to install npm for that project too. Go inside directory and run npm install command.

```
meteor npm install
```

It will take some time and when its complete run your project using following comand.

```
meteor npm start
```

### Possible issues:

#### There are chances your npm install is not successful.

This can be because of some permission issue.

Or it may be because of node version. Please make sure you are using supported platform and node version.

**If you are new to react and want to start with react base app you can use `create-react-app` to start from scratch.**

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Follow the documentation provided on above link.

Comment: He is using a Meteor app, please see my answer for the correct way to install/run the app.

Comment: He can because this meteor app according to the documention is react-based.

Comment: @thakurinbox He linked to a Meteor/React app that he is trying to use.

Comment: That is so true. I just got downvoted but I am referencing the documentation and I even put the link of it in the answer

Comment: @thakurinbox your answer was plain wrong, he is using a Meteor app. It is correct now that you have edited it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use Meteor to run the app. From the Meteor [documentation](https://themeteorchef.com/base/getting-started) linked to in the [README.md](https://github.com/themeteorchef/react-sticky-scroll#the-meteor-chef---base), you must first run the following command to install the dependencies:

```
meteor npm install
```

Followed by the command to start the Meteor application:

```
meteor
```

If you then visit `http://localhost:3000` you will see the Meteor app.